# Limit Oracle object set in SQL Server Migration Assistant

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I have a large Oracle source database with many objects and wish to migrate a comparatively small set of table definitions to a SQL Server instance using Microsoft's dedicated migration tool SSMA. I ran the migration tool previously, having to leave it processing overnight due to the quantity of objects. When I tried to save the project, frustratingly, the machine ran out of memory, taking me back to where I started.

I initially connected as SYSTEM, so created a new user that could select only from the tables for migration, along with CREATE SESSION and CONNECT privileges. This failed on connection to Oracle due to the dictionary tables being inaccessible.

I then added granted SELECT ON ANY DICTIONARY to the new user and connected to the Oracle source. This time, the connection was successful, but I believe the entire dictionary is being read due to the amount of time it's already taken to load the objects into SSMA.

What I would like to know is: is there an easy way to constrain the set of tables being loaded into SSMA, with the intention of speeding up the connection process?

Comment: So you are saying it is taking forever to just download the metadata? If so I weep for your chances of a conversion. Where is the PC you are running this on related to the Oracle and SQL Server hosts?

Comment: I'm actually running it off the SQL Server host - it's just a proof of concept and that's the only Windows machine I currently have access to. I'm guessing the 4gb memory on that box are inhibiting the process somewhat!

Comment: That would probably be a minor issue lol... The other part would be how far across the network it has to go to retrieve the metadata for the Oracle instance. As far as I know there is no way to bypass the initial load. Once you get past that you can select schemas to migrate.

Comment: I've killed the job and trying to get some more memory in the machine. The machines are at separate locations, but <1ms when I ping. Hopefully increasing the memory will help!